# Twitter:image meta tag not showing image for its Twitter card

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Website's title">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="Lorem ipsum dol sor em convectur">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="styles/assetsOptimized/ourStory/StoreFront.jpeg">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://website.com/">
```

Twitter card validation shows as follows: 
[image]

Everything shows in the card except the image.

I have tried:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://styles/assetsOptimized/ourStory/StoreFront.jpeg">
```

These are the Open Graph Meta tags that work for Facebook, placed above the twitter tags(referencing the 11 meta tags found in the twitter validation - `viewport, http-equiv`:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Website's title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum dol sor em convectur">
<meta property="og:image" content="styles/assetsOptimized/ourStory/ourStoryStoreFront.jpeg">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://website.com/">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a relative URL to the image will not work on Twitter with Twitter Cards. You need to include the fully-qualified domain for the site:

`<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://website.com/styles/assetsOptimized/ourStory/StoreFront.jpeg">`

Answer (score 5):

I see the issue is solved but just FYI: An additional issue here is probably the fact twitter's meta tags do not use the `property` attribute but the name attribute, as shown in their documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/summary).

So your code would look like:

```html
  
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://styles/assetsOptimized/ourStory/StoreFront.jpeg">
```

Comment: This actually solved the problem I was having with twitter:image. I was already using absolute URLs but I still had the problem. Turned out my Jekyll plugin used 'property' instead of 'name'.

Answer (score 0):

An associated picture URL won't function with Twitter Cards on Twitter. The site's full-qualified domain name must be included.

you can either create a static file link to host the image and then
use it or you can easly use https://imgbb.com/ to host them

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://i.ibb.co/StoreFront.jpeg">
```

> And you can always test it out before deploying it using metatags, you can find the link over here https://www.techjournal.ai/metatags, and also make sure to check out other social media platforms as well

Best of luck